# Average Waiting Time for mixed distribution function

Tags: probability-distributions

Mixed Distribution Function

$$
F(t) = \begin{cases}
    \hfill 0 \hfill & t < 0 \\
    \hfill p+(1-p)(1-e^{-yt}) & t \geq 0
\end{cases}
$$

How can i find the average waiting time of an arrival and average waiting time for an arrival given that a wait is required.

For part 1: I did this but was struck as the equation is tending to infinity

$$
E(t) = \int_{t=0}^\infty t[p+(1-p)(1-e^{-yt})] \, dt
$$

But this value is tending to infinity when we do integration by part

$$
= \int_{t=0}^\infty tp \, dt + \cdots
$$

The first value is infinity??
Kindly give me some suggestions on this first part. I also don't know what to do with the second one as in my knowledge should be same

Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $F(t)$ is a CDF (cumulative distribution function), not a PDF (probability distribution function).  It gives

$$
F(t) = P(T \leq t)
$$

To determine the average from a CDF, you do not multiply by $t$; you just subtract from $1$ and integrate:

$$
E(T) = \int_{t=0}^\infty [1-F(t)] \, dt
$$

The difference between the two questions is whether you include that impulse of size $p$ at the origin.  If you do not, then the integral is the same, but you should scale upward by the reciprocal of the probability that you have to wait, or $1/(1-p)$.  (That is, you wait longer on average, given that you wait at all.)

Comment: Ack.  Divide by the probability that you *have to wait*, not *do not wait*.  Bleah.